# Different words for a “contract”

Tags: word-usage, difference

While I was searching for the German word for a *contract* (in the general meaning, as a binding agreement between any multiple entities, in any context) in my English-German dictionary I came across two German words: *Vertrag* and *Auftrag*. Both seem to translate to contract, so I would like to ask what the difference between the two words in terms of their meaning and other small nuances, or whether there are any other more widely used words for a contract.

In context, I’ve seen *Vertrag* used more for historical events (such as agreements between two countries) whereas *Auftrag* seems to be used in more everyday cases such as employment. However, I do not have a clue what specifically they refer to, or when to use which. For example, I’ve seen both *Kaufvertrag* and *Kaufauftrag* being used, although I’m not sure whether they mean the same thing. Which word for a contract is used more widely in everyday language?  And apart from this, which one should I use in more specialized cases, for instance, for *social contract* (for which I encountered the use of both words) or for *lease contract* (which seems to be a *Vertrag* for some reason)?

Comment: If you get separate German words for an English term, like Auftrag and Vertrag for contract, why not try the reverse search and put the German terms into the dictionary of your choice? That should have cleared up the confusion fairly quickly.

Comment: @Robert I do wish to give ntrstd11 the benefit of doubt, because he says *both seem to translate to contract* — I think that a dictionary that translates *Auftrag* with *contract* is a bad one, but it sounds like he found it.

Answer (score 19):

Only Vertrag means contract. Vertrag is not limited to historical or important things. Auftrag is a task, an order, or an assignment.

You always have an *Arbeitsvertrag* that describes the relationship between employer and employee, *Mietvertrag* for landlord and tenant, and *Kaufvertrag* for buyer and seller.

Kauf**auf**trag is a buying order (again, Auftrag = order), and it may result in a Kaufvertrag, but it is a separate thing.

Answer (score 5):

The most general and common word for contract is *Vertrag*. There is also *Kontrakt*, which is equally general; I would however consider it obsolescent (though I haven’t found a dictionary marking it as such, so others may feel it is still a regular word). Words for special types of contracts are formed by composition: An employment contract is an *Arbeitsvertrag* and a lease contract can be a *Mietvertrag*, a *Pachtvertrag* or a *Leasingvertrag* depending on context.

Other words that can mean contract in legal language but have, in everyday language, a ring of being less strict and binding include *Abmachung*, *Übereinkunft* and *Vereinbarung*.

There are further synonyms that are especially common in international law (and accordingly history and international politics) such as *Abkommen*, *Übereinkommen*, *Pakt* and *Konvention*: *Nordatlantikpakt*, *Nichtangriffspakt*, *Chemiewaffenübereinkommen*, *Wiener Vertragsrechtskonvention*, *Vertrag über die abschließende Regelung in Bezug auf Deutschland*.

Finally, there are special types of contracts such as the *Vergleich*, in which two parties settle a disagreement by each backing down a bit, or the *Konkordat*, a treaty between the Holy See (representing the Catholic church) and a state.

*Auftrag* cannot normally mean contract.

Answer (score 2):

It does take rather a big strech, but in a bad dictionary I can imagine the word *Auftrag* being somewhere close to *contract*: If and only if you are *contracting* a craftsman to do some work (e.g. repave the driveway) then you would say in German

> Ich *beauftrage* einen Handwerker. Der Handwerker bekommt einen **Auftrag.**

But this stems from different thoughts of what actually happens. *Contracting* someone implies that both sides are at least somewhat equal in the contract agreement, while the German *beauftragen* is a lot closer to *order* — hence everybody’s confusion as to why you’re even asking for those two words.

All *contracts* — meant as in a piece of paper that two parties sign — can and would be translated as *Vertrag* when translated directly. Hence your observation that treaties are often translated with *Vertrag* — although check chirlu’s answer for other possible translations here.

Therefore, it must be *Gesellschafts**vertrag*** (social contract), *Kauf**vertrag*** (contract of purchase), *Miet**vertrag*** (leasing contract) and more. If you substitute *-vertrag* with *-auftrag*, you get valid words, however, they now imply an order (to do something): *Mietauftrag* is the order to lease something, *Kaufauftrag* is the order to buy something — both would be a boss giving them to his employee so that the employee can start searching for offers — and *Gesellschaftsauftrag* would mean something along the lines of *where society is supposed to go*.